# Java NullPointerException с ArrayList

Tags: java

Почему выскакивает NullPointerException, если в функции stringToArray я инициализирую, передавая в качестве параметра SList

```
public class ListsS {
    public ArrayList<String> SList;
    public String str = "a a a";

     private void stringToArray(String string, ArrayList<String> list, String separator){

            list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.split(separator)));
     }

     public void a(){
            stringToArray(str,SList," ");
     }

     public void end(){
            for (String s : skillsList){
                System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Main

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ListS lst = new ListS();
    lst.a();
    lst.end();

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете переписать значение для ссылки `SList` таким образом:

```
stringToArray(str,SList," ");
```

В **java** все параметры передаются по значению. Т.е. данный код создает копию ссылки. Эта ссылка указывает на `null`. В методе вы изменяете ее значение. После этого она указывает на созданный список, но исходная ссылка `SList` осталась неизмененной

Есть несколько вариантов решения:

1) возвращать из метода ссылку на новый список и присваивать ее значение `SList`
2) явно в методе обращаться к полю `SList`
3) Передавать объект содержащий ссылку на `SList` например

```
private void stringToArray(String string, ListsS obj, String separator){
     obj.SList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.split(separator)));
}
```

Comment: спасибо за замечание, поправил

Answer (score 0):

Присвоение значения параметру `list` в `stringToArray` не меняет значение (`null`) члена класса `SList`.

```
 private ArrayList<String> stringToArray(String string, String separator){
   return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string.split(separator)));
 }

 public void a(){
   SList = stringToArray(str, " ");
 }
```

Comment: А почему так? Я же передаю ссылку в метод и там инициализирую

Answer (score 0):

```
ListS lst = new ListS();
```

вы создали новый объект с помощю конструктора по умолчанию. Все поля в нем ровно такие как описано в классе. Т.е. есть обе переменные и `ArrayList` и `String` как неинициализированные переменные типа указывают на объект `null`.

```
lst.a();
```

вы вызываете у этого объекта метод `a()`, который перепоручает работу другому методу, для работы которого требуется обе этих переменных. Обе они в этот момент указывают на `null`. Сплиттер не может работать с нулевой строкой.  Поэтому выбрасывается исключение `NullPointerException`.